# count big table accuracy

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table that can grow and have millions of rows.

And I will need to count this rows everytime, in the same page I can count it for about 10 times for differente users:

```
select count(id) from posts where user = ?
```

So, to avoid this count I'm thinking to create a secound table and increase or decrease this number there to keep a counter.

```
update postscount SET number = number + 1  where user = ?
select number from postscount where user = ?
```

so this select is much faster.

My question is, is it a good practise and what about accuracy, I have a innodb table, can it keep the exactly number of inserts? (If I have simultaneous inserts?)

thank you friends!

Comment: is `user` and `id` indexed? it should not be 'slow'

Comment: @Dagon yeah, not slow, but I'm trying to make the fastest solution I can and less CPU usage for this. to count table posts all the time, if I have 100 users online, each one counting this table with more than million rows, maybe it can slow down things.

Comment: What level of acuracy do you need?

Comment: @JuanCarlosBrown as near as possible. for example, if one user has 5000 posts, it can show 4980... but not 2000.

Comment: and I'm thinking to use this in a "like" system, like facebook too. how facebook count likes? using count? lol

Comment: In that case, most likely it won't hurt as long as you are able to determine the age of the count, you can discard for example counts that are older than 1 minute or something like that. The truth is that facebook is not realtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution without new tables

Normally, MySQL only uses one index per query.
In the case of your query `select count(id) from posts where user = ?`, it could be `user` or `id`, but would be probably `user`, as it's the column in the where clause.

In that case, as both columns are indexed, your query would first use the index to select the rows for the user, but would need to search again on the `id` column (using the index for that column), in order to count the rows, as the count() counts only the values that aren't null.

Given that, you have 2 options (without creating a new table):

1. Create an index with both columns;
2. Only use one of the columns in the select.

Option 1. is clearly a bad option. So, we use option 2.

Given that, as we have to filter by `user`, we alter the count. `count(user)` would be an option, but you can also do `count(1)`. So a better option would be:

```
select count(1) from posts where user = ?
```

You can test both options, by asking mysql to explain you the queries, just prefixing them with `explain`. And, so that your results aren't influenced by the query cache, add `sql_no_cache` after the select word. For example:

```
explain select sql_no_cache count(user) from posts where user = 1

explain select sql_no_cache count(id) from posts where user = 1

explain select sql_no_cache count(id) from posts where user = 1
```

Compare the results. You can check which indexes are used, if mysql creates temp tables, etc, etc. You can make for different users, as the results may be different.

### Solution with new tables

To create a new table, updated every time a user makes a new post, just for this, the gain wouldn't be that big, as every time a row is inserted in posts (and their indexes updated), a new row would be inserted/or updated in the other table (and their indexes updated). The other table would be much smaller, of course, but every insert would be slower. I don't have data for this cases.

If it wouldn't be that much faster, as the volume of data isn't unmanageable for MySQL.

But, you could improve that, by just updating that postcount table every X seconds, every Y user post inserts or use interactions, or so. In that case, you could better use the caches (query cache, innodb caches, etc), don't have many problems with concurrent inserts, etc.

As others posted, a timestamp column for the last update of the row might be useful to force an update after X seconds.

Probably, an update every X seconds, done by a cron/task would be a good solution (and in that case you wouldn't need the timestamp column), as you could take advantage of the query cache: when enabled, mysql stores every select query in that cache, and if you repeat the exact same query (binary comparison) and the table wasn't changed, then mysql returns immediately with the first result, without going to the table. Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html for more info.

### Conclusions

You have 2 options: 1) optimize your query, by only using one index of the column, or 2) create a new table with the counts.

The first option is much simpler, and would probably fits your system. 100 users isn't that much.

The second options is more complicated, more complex to implement, and would give you just slightly better performance.

Also, you may improve your system performance, with configuration improvements of your Mysql server configuration.

Answer (score 2):

if `id` is a primary key (and it should!) with auto increment +1 and you have  indexes `id` and `user`, your first sql should be ok. indexes & keys are important in SQL.

> So, to avoid this count I'm thinking to create a secound table and increase or decrease this number there to keep a counter.

only if you are using trigger in SQL (Update Trigger on second table), instead of using PHP for that.

You can also add an new field in your table like `postindex`, then you can count up individual for each user on a new post and select that (select postindex from user order by postindex DESC).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of counting id for each separate user why not get it for all user using `group by` like

```
select count(id) 
from posts 
group by user;
```

Per your comment, if you are counting the post on each user login then make sure the column you are using in `WHERE` condition (`user`) is indexed and that running the query on per user would be fine. But creating a second table is what I won't do and no that's won't be faster in any means. You will have to execute two statement one for `update` and get the `number` column.

Again, you can the get the count for all user as I said first and then cache it in your application end (cached values are global generally) then in all user sessions you can use the same cached data and no need of firing a separate query every time.

Comment: I'm trying to count all the "posts" each user in particular has, so for each user I need to count, run all table to count his/her posts

Comment: That was missing in your question. see edit in answer.

Answer (score 1):

I won't say it is a good practice but it is a common practice. I've had to do similar things in the past specially in systems that can grow out of proportion easily. Make sure to include a timestamp so you know how old the count it and refresh/discard it depending on the age. This should lower the impact on your database, however you should be carefull when doing this kind of things. Other solution may be counting the posts for every user every X amount of time.